# WPF recordset listbox databind?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, adodb, recordset

how can i bind my records to the itemsource of a list box?

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\mvdata.accdb;"

cn.Open()

    If rs.State = True Then rs.Close()
    rs.Open("Select * from company", cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic,ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

    slistbox.ItemsSource = ?????
```

Hope someone cud help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill `DataTable` by the data from recordset first, then set `ListBox`'s ItemsSource to the `DataTable`. Something like this:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\mvdata.accdb;"

cn.Open()

    If rs.State = True Then rs.Close()
    rs.Open("Select * from company", cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic,ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
    Dim oleDbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
    oleDbAdapter.Fill(dataTable, rs)

    slistbox.ItemsSource = dataTable
```

I didn't compile it, but I hope you got the idea

Comment: why it doesn't recognize DataTable() it says DataTable not defined. am i missing something?